# VBA Sum/Count Calculations of Column Ranges on Conditional Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to run quick calculations on columns across multiple worksheets when a certain condition is met.

I need to get the count of marked cells within a column range over several worksheets where the worksheet's name begins with "BC" and have the results returned to a cell on another sheet.

Can someone help?

```
''Generating worksheets from list of values
Sub CreateTemplates()
    Set Template = Sheets("Test New Format")
    For Each cell in Range("lstbc")
        If cell <> "" Then
            Template.Copy After:=Sheets(4)
            ActiveSheet.Name = "BC" & cell.Value
            cell.Offset(0,1).Value = "BC" & cell
        End If
    Next
End Sub

''Loop through sheets that begin with BC & calculate count
Sub LoopSheets()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myTotal as Double
    Dim ProcessNum as Integer

    ProcessNum = 0 

    For Each wb in Workbooks
        For Each ws in Worksheets
            Debug.Print ws.Name
            If InStr(1, Left(ws.Name,2), "BC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                myTotal = myTotal+1
                ProcessNum = ProcessNum + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E9:E116"))
            End If
        Next ws
    Next wb
    Sheets("console").Range("c18").Value = ProcessNum
End Sub
```

I have 3 worksheets generated that contain "BC" in their name. The count from myTotal gives me 3 (that seems good), but when I try to get the count from the column range from each of those sheets, I don't get the correct results at all.

Comment: The way that CountA is being called is incorrect. I don't know what Range is   when used by itself like that. If you're not using OPTION EXPLICIT it may be a new variable. The second parameter refers to a range, but it doesn't include any worksheet, so it defaults to the ActiveSheet.

Comment: `CreateTemplates` is incoherent: you set a reference to a sheet to `Template` and `Copy` from it, but `Range("lstbc")` is never qualified. You also refer to `Sheets(4)` where 4 could refer to anything. You also use `ActiveSheet` and further do not qualify which sheet you think `cell` should belong to (implied it is the mystery sheet to which `Range("lstbc")` belongs to I guess). Anyway - you need to fix all those things.